# Distribute the capacity of a variable in the group values PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with clients in each city, and each client order a quantity of products, but each city has a limited stock. What I want is to distribute the stock and labeled clients with "in" if the stock is enough to supply the order and "out" if we don't have products for that client. The clients are ordered by importance ( smaller the most important).

```
City | client | Order | Stock |
_______________________________
1    | 1      | 10    | 22    |
1    | 2      | 8     | 22    |
1    | 3      | 12    | 22    |
1    | 4      | 4     | 22    |
2    | 1      | 3     | 10    |
2    | 2      | 4     | 10    |
2    | 3      | 1     | 10    |
```

the output could be something like this:

```
City | client | Order | Stock | In/out |
_______________________________________
1    | 1      | 10    | 22    | in     |
1    | 2      | 8     | 22    | in     |
1    | 3      | 12    | 22    | in     |
1    | 4      | 4     | 22    | out    |
2    | 1      | 3     | 10    | in     |
2    | 2      | 4     | 10    | in     |
2    | 3      | 1     | 10    | in     |
```

Here is some data to work with:

```
df_dict = dict(
        City = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
        client = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3],
        Order = [10,8,12,4,3,4,1],
        Stock = [22,22,22,22,10,10,10]
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

Comment: How can you in for the client 3 in City 1

Comment: can you post the data in a more copy/pastable format? it's kind of a hassle to clean all those junk characters up

Comment: @BEN_YO because I consider a partial assortment as successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.where(condition, option-conditionTRUE,option-conditionUNTRUE)`

In this case the `condition` is a `Boolean query` checking if the `difference` between the `stock` and `cumulative orders` is `less than/equal` to `0`

```
import numpy as np

df['in/out']=np.where(df.groupby('City').apply(lambda x: x['Stock'].sub(x['Order'].cumsum()).le(0)),'out','in')



City  client  Order  Stock in/out
0     1       1     10     22     in
1     1       2      8     22     in
2     1       3     12     22    out
3     1       4      4     22    out
4     2       1      3     10     in
5     2       2      4     10     in
6     2       3      1     10     in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.groupby` the appropriate columns (let's say city) and take the cumulative sum. If the cumulative sum exceeds the `Stock`, then it is `out`. It depends on what row you want to define `out`. Below is the first way, but you could also shift one row:

```
df['In/out'] = ((df.groupby('City')['Order'].cumsum() > df['Stock'])
                .replace([True,False], ['out','in']))
df
Out[1]: 
   City  client  Order  Stock In/out
0     1       1     10     22     in
1     1       2      8     22     in
2     1       3     12     22    out
3     1       4      4     22    out
4     2       1      3     10     in
5     2       2      4     10     in
6     2       3      1     10     in
```